# How to insert image into lightning-input-rich-text programmatically?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, inputrichtext

I have an image in base64 format and I want to push the image data explicitly into my lightning-input-rich-text. Is there any way?

My code looks like this:

```html
 <lightning-input-rich-text 
     value={body} 
     label="EmailBody" 
     placeholder="Email Body" 
 >
 </lightning-input-rich-text>
```

and in my JS Controller I am trying to do this

```js
this.body = this.filesUploaded[0]['VersionData']
// this.filesUploaded[0]['VersionData'] represent the base64 format data
```

Instead of showing the image my `lightning-input-rich-text` shows base64 in string for ex: ('iVBORw0KGgoAAAA....')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some docs the answer comes out to be

```
this.body = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + this.filesUploaded[0]['VersionData'] + '" />';
```